# Validation Failed using Cocoon for Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, cocoon-gem

I have the following models in my schema:

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :impacts, as: :impactable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :impacts, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Impact < ApplicationRecord
  #association
  belongs_to :impactable, polymorphic: true

  #enum
  enum impact_type: [:full_school, :standard, :section]
end
```

Whenever I try to save a notification now - I get the an error - `Validation failed: Impacts impactable must exist`

I've tried to create impacts from notifications manually with `Notification.last.impacts.create` and they work fine.

What could be the problem here?

More info - 
When I add a byebug to the @notification object before it saves in the controller - this is the output -

```
>> @notification
=> #<Notification id: nil, notification_type: "email", title: "Test", content: "Tomorrow is a holiday", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

And also checking for it's associations --

```
>> @notification.impacts
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Impact id: nil, impact_type: "standard", standard: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, impactable_id: nil, impactable_type: "Notification", section: "">]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add  `inverse_of: :impactable` to your Notifications Model.

```
has_many :impacts, as: :impactable, inverse_of: :impactable
```